# Where to ask CV questions

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is there any place here on Stack Exchange where I can ask questions about CVs or resumes for a software developer/engineering role?

In my case I am curious if using a monospaced / text editor font is a good choice ([Consolas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consolas), [Menlo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menlo_(typeface)), etc.) to give it a nice developer touch.

[image]

Comment: Definitely not the place here, but dear God don't ever write your resume like that.  If I have a stack of 50+ resumes to read, that'll be the first one to hit the floor.

Comment: I found that actually quite cool :-| uff.. ok, will look for another one

Comment: Just stick to a resume template you can find online, I've used one I found like 10 years ago and I still get compliments about it ;)

Comment: `Think about the HR filter (they will probably not` *get it*).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Probably you are searching for:

https://workplace.stackexchange.com

They already have a [resume](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resume) tag.

But before posting your questions, be sure that they are on-topic on site:

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic